# JAVA curly braces

Tags: java, braces

Receiving a syntax error on my curly braces but no matter how many I close it still gives an error. Can't figure it out. Thank you for any advice on this I am at a loss. I have tried adding more and removing more. I had the count of how many I needed to close but still getting an error.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Paint1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        double wallHeight = 0.0;
        double wallWidth = 0.0;
        double wallArea = 0.0;
        double gallonsPaintNeeded = 0.0;
        
        final double squareFeetPerGallons = 350.0;
        
        // Implement a do-while loop to ensure input is valid
        // Prompt user to input wall's height
        do {
            
        System.out.println("Enter wall height (feet): ");
        wallHeight = scnr.nextDouble();
            while (!scnr.hasNextInt()) {
                System.out.printf("\"%s\" is not a valid number.\n");
                System.out.println("Please enter wall height in feet: ");
            } while (wallHeight < 0) {
            
        
        // Implement a do-while loop to ensure input is valid
        // Prompt user to input wall's width
            do {
        System.out.println("Enter wall width (feet): ");
        wallWidth = scnr.nextDouble(); // changed wallHeight to wallWidth
        while (!scnr.hasNextDouble()) {
            System.out.printf("\"%s\" is not a valid number.\n");
            System.out.println("Please enter wall width in feet: ");
        } while (wallWidth < 0) {
        
        
            
        
        // Calculate and output wall area
        wallArea = wallHeight * wallWidth;
        System.out.println("Wall area: " + wallArea + " square feet"); // added variable

        // Calculate and output the amount of paint (in gallons) needed to paint the wall
        gallonsPaintNeeded = wallArea/squareFeetPerGallons;
        System.out.println("Paint needed: " + gallonsPaintNeeded + " gallons"); // changed variable to correct case
        
            }
}
```

Comment: your compiler should give you a hint of where it is missing

Comment: You have a `do { ...` which needs to end with a `} while (condition);`. So the `{` after `while (wallWidth < 0)` isn't allowed. Do you intend to use a new loop right after the do-while?

Comment: You should edit your question to include the exact error, as text.

Answer (score 1):

you tried to implement a do while loop but there is an error.

You have to make it look like that

```
do {
//something
//something
}while(condition);
```

You can read more about this loop here : https://www.javatpoint.com/java-do-while-loop

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an extra curly brace in the `} while (wallWidth < 0) {` line. Have you tried removing that? The opening brace is fine, but the one at the end of the line might be giving you issues.

Answer (score 0):

You got some issues with your do while loops.

The `do` on line and 19 and on line 29 never gets closed and is missing the while clause at the end. Besides that you are missing 4 curly braces.

```
public class Paint1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //...
        do {
            //...
            while (!scnr.hasNextInt()) {
                //..
            }
            while (wallHeight < 0) {
                // ..
                do {
                    // ..
                    while (!scnr.hasNextDouble()) {
                    }
                    while (wallWidth < 0) {
                    }
                } while (true); // Should have a clause, or will be an infinite loop
            }
        } while (true); // Should have a clause, or will be an infinite loop
    }
}
```